# How do you do solid of revolution if the revolving axis passes through the region?

Tags: calculus

So what I got here is to find the volume when the area between $x^2$ and $x^4$ on the first quadrant is revolved by $x=\frac58$. It shows that the revolving axis passes through the graph, and I have no idea how to deal with the original method. $(\frac58,\frac13)$ is the centroid of this region.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the intersection of the region with its reflection with respect to the line $x=5/8$

The remedy is not too complicated.

Sketch the reflection along with the original region and rotate the  two non-intersecting parts on the right side of the line $x=5/8$ separately and then add the results together. This way you are avoiding counting the intersection twice.

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't understand it clearly (my understanding problem). Can you elaborate what you meant to say?

Comment: Sketch the graph of both functions and their reflections about the line $x=5/8$. Now look at the part which is on the right side of the line $x=5/8$ and divide it into two parts which do not intersect. Rotate each part and add the results.